# CSS picture display on blog

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and try to write a blog. I cannot figure out one issue.

I have a code that takes the picture, title and descriptions on the post and displays in the mainpages.

However, I only want picture which covers all of the box and nothing else. No topic, no explanations.
How can I do that? I am so newbie that I really cannot locate where the important part is so I am giving you the full code.

[image: This is what I am trying to do]

This is my blog http://www.alphabitrage.com/

This is full code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/449db483824c113e283b

After answers from @Pham Mim Tim:

In my code this is not very neat the section you mentioned is this:

```css
  <div class='post hentry uncustomized-post-template simpleCart_shelfItem'>
                  <a expr:name='data:post.id'/>
                  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
                    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
                      <h3 class='post-title entry-title'>
                        <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
                          <a expr:href='data:post.link'>
                            <data:post.title/>
                          </a>
                          <b:else/>
                          <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
                            <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
                              <data:post.title/>
                            </a>
                            <b:else/>
                            <data:post.title/>
                          </b:if>
                        </b:if>
                      </h3>
                    </b:if>
                  </b:if>
                  <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
                  <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
                    <div class='post-body entry-content'>
                      <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
                        <div class='simpleCart_shelfItem'>
                          <div class='item_name'>
                            <data:post.title/>
                          </div>
```

I am really newbie and can't find where to put it.

Comment: You can use this cover images as a background images.

Comment: What do you mean by cover images?

Comment: @nilly: You can see my answer below :)

Comment: @PhamMinhTan thanks I hope I clarified a little bit more for you.

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is to set width & height of the picture too 100%, and remove all the stuff you don't want

Comment: How can I do that, code is really crappy so I can't find where to manipulate.

Comment: Is this a site created with a site creator offered to you by your website host provider? As long as you have access to to html file and the css file you should be able to edit the document

Comment: I have access but this was a template and tweaked a little. Thats why I am having diffulties.

Comment: It says the github link you provided was not found. But if you can find the right element in the css file and html file you should be able to do it yourself

Comment: Pham Minh Tan's answer seemed to work, but I know you want to only have the picture, so i suggest that you figure out what the things are you want removed by adding '<!--<div>example</div>-->' to random things in the div and if it works keep it there

Comment: Ok thanks I will try

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="post hentry uncustomized-post-template simpleCart_shelfItem" style="
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mr47aQjV7OA/VclBCc5-CkI/AAAAAAAAAIE/jbG1B4DCPRE/s1600/rsz_2img_3346.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
">
```

You can use `background-size: cover` with this images you want to make full cover with blogs.

Comment: I added the section in my codes. Where do you think your code goes?

Comment: You only add this style into your blog post. I add this style into your page on inspect elements. You can see in this images: http://i.imgur.com/NL7VlE7.png

Comment: Sorry this gives 404

Comment: After see your update: You only add `style="
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mr47aQjV7OA/VclBCc5-CkI/AAAAAAAAAIE/jbG1B4DCPRE/s1600/rsz_2img_3346.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;` as inline-style in this div have class post.

Comment: I am not sure about that because in my code, I never specify links, it takes from the pictures I uploaded to blog.

Comment: Of course, in my answer it's just a example to make you see a result from it. you can replace this link with your code. I don't know your code is. I guess that maybe: `<div class='post hentry uncustomized-post-template simpleCart_shelfItem' style="background: url(data:post.img_url) no-repeat; background-size: cover">`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I knew your requirement.

1. Just set the box's css like {position:relative;}
2. And set the picture's css like

`{
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:2;
    }`

Then maybe my work can suit you requirement.
Hope your success and reply.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but the problem is where in my code should I put this? My code is really hard to understand.

Comment: Picture has an automaic css that takes data from post. That is why it is getting complicated.

Comment: I have seen your github code,and it 's truely complicated.I know you are a newbie.But can you use the "developer tool of chrome",press F12 at your chrome and you can use the "developer tool" to find and fix you code!Just try it